# Can a flow action be packaged?

Tags: managed-package, process-builder, visual-workflow

This may sound simple but I'm trying to understand if a flow action or lightning component be part of a managed package? The idea is to call these flow components from process builder or cloud flow builder.

Answer (score 2):

Yes both flow actions and lightning components can be included in managed packages.

The ISV Guide is your best resource for what can be included in a managed package and all of the considerations for each type of component.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm

Also from the [documentation of Flow Actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_distribute_internal_action.htm):

> 6. If necessary, change the name of the action.
>
> **This name is used in the API and managed packages.** It must begin with a letter and use only alphanumeric characters and underscores, and it can’t end with an underscore or have two consecutive underscores. Unless you’re familiar with working with the API, we suggest not editing this field.